# Formula to show text based on numbers

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for a short way to type this:

```
=if(a1=1,"sometext",if(a1=2,"othertext",if(a1=3,"thirdtext")))
```

In JavaScript you would do something similar like this:

```
switch(a1)
   case 1: "sometext"
   case 2: "othertexT"
   case 3: "thirdtext"
```

There is formula that can handle multiple values?

Comment: In other words. I am searching for a "conditional text". Like "conditional format"...

Comment: Thanks for posting Amina. The `VLOOKUP` formula is very useful !! If you search Web Applications, you will find multiple cases involving the usage of the `VLOOKUP` formula: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=vlookup. Welcome on Web Applications !!

Comment: Welcome again......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly more in keeping with OP's example:

```
=switch(A1,1,"sometext",2,"othertext","thirdtext")
```

(using "thirdtext" as the default for anything other than `1` or `2`, but inserting `3,` would avoid that).

The above does not require a keys/values table but such a table may reduce typing if required often. However in that case **two** columns (or rows) are required for a VLOOKUP, say:

```
=vlookup(a1,othersheet!a1:b3,2,false)
```

which may be abbreviated with a named range to, for example:

```
=vlookup(A1,Table,2,0)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found how to do it using vlookup.

I have twos sheet. in one sheet I put keys and values

```
1  somtext
2  othertext
3  thirdtext
```

In the second sheet

```
=vlookup(a1,othersheet!a1:a3,2,false)
```